# How to stop refresh-registration in pjsip

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip

I am developing an Android VOIP(Voice Over IP) Dialer(SIP Client) by using PJSIP Stack. Currently I am sending SIP Registration & Refresh-Registration to SIPProxy Server periodically for every 60 seconds, if initial SIP-Registration  succeeds.In my application, the only case I stop sending Register messages to the Server is by sending Un-Register Message to SIP Server.

My Requirement is, my dialer should send SIP-Register to SIP-Server only once whenever I am opening my Voip dialer.The main purpose of this registration is doing SIP-Authorization.If the authorization is successful, my dialer will allow them to make call otherwise my application should not move to next page.

Kindly help me how to stop sending Refresh-Register in PJSIP Stack.